# usage of "but" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage

can anyone tell me the meaning of "There was not anyone in the room but liked his singing"
Is this sentence correct and if it is, then could anyone explain to me it's meaning.

Comment: The sentence doesn't sound correct to me.

Comment: I'd read that as an archaic usage meaning 'there was no-one in the room who didn't like his singing'.  You can think of it as 'There was not anyone in the room but (those people who) liked his singing.'

Comment: The answers in this related question may be useful http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286732/what-does-this-archaic-use-of-fear-never-but-you-mean-exactly

Answer (score 1):

This is an obsolescent use of *but*, which the OED explains as:

> 14 b. With omission of the pronominal subject or object of the subord. clause, so that *but* acts as a negative relative: That..not, who..not. (Latin *quin*.)

So the meaning is "There was not anyone in the room that did not like his singing."

'But' is often used this way in literature up to the 19th century, but it is rare nowadays.

Comment: There are a few expressions that use this sense: "we can but try", and "I was but a lad" for example. Even these are infrequently seen now.

Comment: I don't think that _is_ the same sense, @HughMeyers: in your examples you can replace _but_ by _only_ or _just_. What makes the original sentence hard to understand is that you can't replace it by a single word